# Are these independent probability events? Why or why not?

Tags: probability

Suppose company {X} represents clients in buying inventory during automated (online) auctions. The client chooses the bid value beforehand, and {X} repeatedly makes that bid in the automated auctions which are constantly occurring throughout the day. (Bid value is constant). Consider that for any given auction, {X} may have two or more clients which want to buy the exact same inventory, so in these cases {X} must choose which client to represent in the auction. In order to do this, {X} conducts an automated auction (hereafter referred to as the **internal** auction) to determine which client that {X} will choose to submit a bid for in the real auction (hereafter referred to as the **external** auction). Based on the highest bid value, {X} chooses exactly one client from the internal auction to represent in the external auction. The results of the external auction are entirely outside of {X}'s control.

So, a client's bid must win {X}'s internal auction in order to be submitted as a bid in the external auction.

Empirically, it appears that the probability of winning the internal auction **and** the external auction is equal to the **product** of these two probabilities: (1) the probability of winning the internal auction, and (2) assuming the client's bid has *already* been chosen to be submitted to the external auction as a precondition, the probability of winning the external auction.

In what way(s) are these two events (internal and external auctions) considered independent events, if at all? Why or why not?

Comment: The client's bid value influences the probability of winning both internal and external auctions. Bid value for a client remains constant in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_i \in [0, +\infty)$ the bid of the $i$th client. We can hypotize that $B_i$ is a random variable and each $B_i$ is independent from the others.

**Internal auction**
If there are $n$ clients, then the probability that $i$th client wins the internal auction is:

$$p_i^{IA} = \mathbb{P}\left\{B_i = \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j\right\} = \mathbb{P}\left\{B_i > B_1 \wedge B_i > B_2 \ldots B_i > B_n \right\}.$$

**External auction**
For the external auction, we need to consider other clients. We denote their bids with $B'_i$, with $i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$.

Given that $i$th client won the internal auction, then the probability to win the external is:

$$p_i^{EA} = \mathbb{P}\left\{B_i > \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j' \left. \right|B_i = \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j\right\} .$$

**Both auctions**
$i$ wins both auctions with the following probability:

$$p_i^{IEA} = \mathbb{P}\left\{B_i > \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j' \wedge B_i = \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j\right\}.$$

Recall that:

$$\mathbb{P}\{X | Y\} = \frac{\mathbb{P}\{X \wedge Y\}}{\mathbb{P}\{ Y\}}.$$
In particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent if
$$\mathbb{P}\{X | Y\} = \mathbb{P}\{X\}$$
which means that
$$\mathbb{P}\{X \wedge Y\} = \mathbb{P}\{X\}\mathbb{P}\{Y\}.$$

In our case:

$$\mathbb{P}\left\{B_i > \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j' \left. \right|B_i = \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j\right\} =\\= \frac{\mathbb{P}\left\{B_i > \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j' \wedge B_i = \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j\right\}}{\mathbb{P}\left\{B_i = \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j\right\}}.$$

Substituting, you get:

$$p_i^{EA} = \frac{p_i^{IEA}}{p_i^{IA}} \Rightarrow p_i^{IEA} = p_i^{EA}p_i^{IA}.$$

Then, yes, $p_i^{IEA}$ is the product of $p_i^{EA}$ and $p_i^{IA}$. Moreover, the events $$B_i > \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j'$$ and $$B_i = \max_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}}B_j$$ are independent.

**Addition**

"$\wedge$" means "AND".

Answer (score 1):

Winning the external auction is clearly dependent on winning the internal auction, since you have $0$ probability of winning the external if you didn't win the internal (since you are never entered), thus your probability of winning the external auction is identical to your probability of winning both auctions, because winning the external auction implies you also won the internal.

Comment: FYI, $P((X\vert Y)\vert Y)$ is a non existent entity, by the way $(X\vert Y)$ is not an event, actually $(X\vert Y)$ does not exist either.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm playing somewhat fast and loose with my symbols.  The point is that conditionals are trivially independent of their conditions.  I'm looking at conditionals as similar to implication in propositional logic, and pointing out that $P \implies (P \implies Q)$ is equivalent to $P \implies Q$

Comment: Honestly I think the intended answer is no, because as you say, $X\vert Y$ is not an event per se, so (winning the external auction given that you already won the internal auction)  can't be one of the "events" referred to in the question "are these two events independent", so the events in question must be (you win the internal auction) and (you win the external auction), which as I said, are dependent.  The one other possibility I suppose is that the two events being considered are (you win the internal auction)  and (your bid is sufficient to win the external auction, should it be entered).

Comment: "conditionals are trivially independent of their conditions" Again, I have no idea what this could mean. "Their conditions" clearly refers to Y, an event, hence "conditionals" should refer to another event, but which event? (X|Y)? Absurd again.

Comment: I guess what I mean is $P(X\vert Y)=P(X\vert (Y \and Y))$

Comment: $P(X\mid Y)=P(X\mid Y\cap Y)$ is (meaningful and) true but I am not sure this is the point you were trying to make...

Comment: Once I look up the LaTeX for the and-symbol, I'll rephrase it that way.

Comment: `\land` $ $ $ $

Comment: It is.  However, I think I'll just delete the top half of the post, because I think it was answering the wrong question.